# Make OfficeJs Word Add-in always appear on the ribbon

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

I am IT for a big organization and I am able to make sure COMM and VSTO Word Add-in always appear on the users's ribbon.

However, we just got a OfficeJs Word Addin, deployed using Sharepoint Catalog as we have Exchange on Prem for O365. I am not able to make it pop up for the users.

Users need to go to My Add-ins, Admin managed/Share folder and then add the Addin. This is decreasing the traction as users are forgetting how to get there.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this article cover what you want to do? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

Comment: We actually tried to use this, and got into trouble. It tags by document, and user sent the document to a counter-party who did not have our plugin. This feature tried to open our plugin for them too, which caused issues.

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to get Word to auto-open an add-in for some users, but not for others.

Comment: COMM and VSTO add-in show up on the Ribbon when opening Word though. Can we not do this for Office-JS?